# How can you split a String on all whitespace with a regular expression in AS3?

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, split

**Please Note:**  I am fully aware that this and other questions similar to it have been asked a million times, but as I have searched the Internet, I have pretty much always run into two problems in these cases:

1. The question is something a little different, like purging all whitespace, as opposed to splitting on it.
2. The answer given, even when accepted, is wrong.  I don't understand why this point is true so much of the time here, and I agree that something's strange about this, but it is.  I have tried people's "accepted" answers, on multiple occasions, and found that they have simply not been debugged at all.

So here's my question:  I want to be able to take a String in AS3 and split it into an array on *any* and *every* whitespace character.  Just like:

```
var arry:Array = ("This is a string.").split(" ");
```

except that I want to essentially use a wildcard character that encompasses any whitespace character.  I want to use a regular expression to avoid excessive function calls and stuff like that.

How can this be done?   Thanks.

Comment: Follow the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555939/using-regexp-to-split-string-but-store-whitespace-space-or-crlf-to-items) but use the simpler expression `/\s+/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.split allows for a regular expression delimiter. '\s' is for whitespace. The examples below produce the same array output.

```
var arry = ("This is a string.").split(/\s/);
var arry = ("This is\ta\nstring.").split(/\s/);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I tried \s before, but maybe I was doing something wrong.